# Suppress EF core 3.0.x initialized msg

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I have:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) 
{
  string connectionString = "mydb.db;";
  optionsBuilder
  .UseLoggerFactory(MainWorker.ConsoleLoggerFactory)
  .EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true)
  .UseSqlite(connectionString);
}
```

Whenever I access my DBContext the console shows

> info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
>         Entity Framework Core 3.0.0-preview4.19176.6 initialized

Is there a way to filter out this particular message ? as I do a lot of queries it just clutters my console debug window ..

Comment: So which is it?  `ef-core-2.0`? `ef-core2.1`? `ef-core-2.2`?

Comment: Why are you telling the logger to use the console if you don't want it to log to the console?

Comment: @MickyD - there is no stackoverflow tag for EFCore 3.0 which is what I'm really after, but I couldn't find any info for any EFCore version

Comment: @Eric Phillips - becasue I want other messages to show just not this one

Comment: So use the [Adapter Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) to wrap the console Logger and ignore that message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EF Core specific log messages are configured via [DbContextOptionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder.configurewarnings?view=efcore-2.1) method (yeah, the name is a bit misleading).

The `EventId` of the message in question is `CoreEventId.ContextInitialized`. And you suppress it using `Ignore`:

```
optionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings
    .Ignore(CoreEventId.ContextInitialized));
```

Of course it can be chained with the other `optionsBuilder` calls. Also you may want to suppress the second context lifetime related log message with `CoreEventId.ContextDisposed`.