# How to enable logging in EF Core 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core 3 Preview 5 and ASP.NET Core 3 Preview 5. In my Debug Output Window of Visual Studio 2019 I get no logs from EF Core. I read the documentation, but after that I am even more confused:

1. According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder.useloggerfactory?view=efcore-2.1 logging should be setup automatically:

> There is no need to call this method when using one of the 'AddDbContext' methods. 'AddDbContext' will ensure that the ILoggerFactory used by EF is obtained from the application service provider.

That is not my experience though.

2. I tried to enable logging by injecting the `ILoggerFactory` to `ConfigureServices` (I intended to then pass it on to `DbContextOptionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory`, but that's not possible anymore, see https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/353

So, how do I setup logging to the debug output windows in EF Core 3.0? Thanks!

Comment: Have you taken a look on it please: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging

Comment: The reason for the close votes is that you *didn't* post any code that can reproduce the issue. For all anyone knows, you may not have enabled logging at all, or log only information messages. There are  questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56419481/suppress-ef-core-3-0-x-initialized-msg) that ask how to turn down logging. The default logging configuration writes to the console, debug output and event log

Comment: OK, I understand. I meanwhile also found the reason: a breaking change in EF Core 3.0. SQL queries are now only shown in Debug mode. I should have checked more if there was an output from EF core at all. I was heading in the wrong direction. The mentioned breaking change: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#query-execution-is-logged-at-debug-level also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55997906/net-core-3-0-consoleloggerfactory-for-sqlite?rq=1

Comment: One should note this change will get reverted again: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/14523

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Update for 3.0 RTM and later:** The log level reverted to Information. Check [filtering what is logged](https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/extensions-logging?tabs=v3#filtering-and-other-configuration) in the docs for more details. See also the [list of categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/simple-logging#message-categories) that can be used for filtering in `appsettings.json`.

---

EF Core logs at the `Debug` level, but the default level used by the host builder is `Information`. The logging level will thus have to be manually set to `Trace` or `Debug`.

By default, this code won't log any EF events :

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = Host
        .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)             
        .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
        {
            var configuration = context.Configuration;
            services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("someConnection")));                    
        })                
        .Build();

    using (var ctx = host.Services.GetRequiredService<MyContext>())
    {
        var cnt = await ctx.Customers.CountAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(cnt);
    }            
}
```

It will only log this event :

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
  Entity Framework Core 3.0.0-preview6.19304.10 initialized 'ConsolidatorsContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
```

To log EF events we need to change the logging level for EF Core events to `Trace` or `Debug` through `appsettings.json` or code. For example, including this in `appsettings.json` :

```
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore":"Debug"
        }
    },
```

Will log EF events :

```
  dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10401]
        An 'IServiceProvider' was created for internal use by Entity Framework.
  info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
        Entity Framework Core 3.0.0-preview6.19304.10 initialized 'MyContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
  dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20000]
        Opening connection to database 'Customers' on server '10.0.0.216'.
  dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20001]
        Opened connection to database 'Customers' on server '10.0.0.216'.
  dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20100]
        Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM [Customers] AS [c]
  dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
        Executed DbCommand (42ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM [Customers] AS [c]
  4
  dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20300]
        A data reader was disposed.
  dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20002]
        Closing connection to database 'Customers' on server '10.0.0.216'.
  dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20003]
        Closed connection to database 'Customers' on server '10.0.0.216'.
  dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10407]
        'MyContext' disposed.
```

Answer (score 5):

There is another critical reason why logging may not occur: That comment on `AddDbContext()` has an unmentioned dependency.

> There is no need to call this method when using one of the
>   'AddDbContext' methods. 'AddDbContext' will ensure that the
>   ILoggerFactory used by EF is obtained from the application service
>   provider.

It only works if your `DbContext` injects `DbContextOptions<T>` into the `base` constructor.

E.g. an auto-generated constructor from `Scaffold-DbContext`

```
public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) 
   : base(options)
{
}
```

That injected object has been setup with a LoggerFactory, so if you don't do it like this, you will have to manually set the logger in your OnConfiguring() method.

Comment: It still doesn't work using AddDbContext<MyDbContext>();

Comment: No idea how to respond to such a vague, drive-by comment.

Comment: I was trying to get the logger factory from the options but it was always null. As it turns out that's not really needed and then the comment actually makes sense.